# "Broadcast" or "broadcasted"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, differences, verbs, past-participles

I'm not a native English speaker, so sorry if this is a very basic question. Is *broadcast* a verb? If it is, what is the simple past and past participle: *broadcasted*?

Comment: Good question.  I've heard both "broadcast" and "broadcasted" being used for the past tense of the verb.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, *broadcast* is a verb, and [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/broadcast) says either *broadcast* or *broadcasted* is acceptable as the simple past and past participle.

However, [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+was+broadcast%2Cit+was+broadcasted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20was%20broadcast%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20was%20broadcasted%3B%2Cc0) shows that *broadcast* is by far the preferred version.

[image]

A study on this very issue can be found [here](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/broadcast-vs-broadcasted-as-past-form/).

Comment: Besides the words mentioned in the article, I think that this little quirk also applies to _telecast_. But it curiously does not seem to have the same effect on _forecast_.

Comment: -1 for stating that broadcast is the "preferred version". To be aware that you are using a word and prefering it requires you to be aware of at least one more option. Not everyone can be said to have preferred the use of "broadcast" to "broadcasted".

Comment: @DrOtka - Any native speaker of English has an intuitive understanding of the use of the "-ed" suffix, so there is no way they could *not* be aware of that option.